# devtools build_vignette can't find functions

Tags: r, devtools

If I use `devtools::use_vignette("my-vignette")` in my package, running `devtools::build_vignette()` works fine.

However, once I add a call to anything from my package, it stops working, with error `could not find function "myfunc"`. If I add a `library(mypackage)` call, I get the error `there is no package called 'mypackage'`.

(I should note that my package checks, builds & installs perfectly cleanly [with no vignettes], and running `devtools::load_all()` also works fine for interactive sessions.)

I know that if I build & install my package, I can then get the vignettes built. This seems like a really inefficient and dangerous way to develop; essentially forcing me to re-build and re-install the entire package on every commit, to test that the vignette isn't breaking.

Is there another way to get the vignette to recognize the package-in-progress?

Comment: FWIW:  I was having similar issues and realized I was not exporting my functions (using @export in .R file and then with roxygen generating a NAMESPACE with export commands).  Does the NAMESPACE file export the function that can't be found when vignette building?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using RStudio IDE (which is very helpful for package developpement), you can render your Rmd document created by `devtools::use_vignette`, by clicking on the **Knit button**. It will create a preview version of your vignette.
By the way, RStudio IDE provides you with helpful shortkeys and buttons to execute your Rmd document chunk by chunk to test if it's working.

If you are not using RStudio IDE, you could render your document without building the package by using the function `rmarkdown::render`.

However, in order to be working, your vignette requires your package to be loaded. So, as you said, you'll have to call `library(mypackage)` and so your package have to be installed.
You can install your package without the vignette in the command line with `devtools::install(build_vignette = FALSE)`. In the RStudio IDE, the button `Build & Reload` is enougth to intall your package.`

Another solution for non user of Rstudio  IDE is to use `devtools::load_all(path to your package)` in your vignette in order to simulate the installation of your package in the vignette environment. Then you can build your vignette with  `devtools::build vignette` whithout needing to install your package before.

I should underline that vignette is build automatically when your build your package. So, when development are finish, replace in the vignette `devtools::load_all` by `library` because your package is loaded before building the vignette when you build a package.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but this did not answer my question at all.

Comment: It is the way I work when I develop. 
If you do a `devtools::load_all` then execute all r chunks in your document without *building* the vignette, they will run in your environnement so your packge function will be found. 
Otherwise, `devtools::install` + `rmarkdown::render` should work : did you tried?
You may also try a `devtools::load_all(path_to_your_package_folder)` at the beggining of the vignette to simulate the installation when knitting. Worth a try.

Comment: Using `devtools::load_all` works, although it does add an undesired dependency on devtools. If you edit that into your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I edited the vignette. For me, devtools should not be add as dependency because you should use 'library' in the vignette when you want to release the package. It should work because building package builds also the vignette after loading package.

Comment: Running a check on the package with `devtools::load_all()` in the vignette creates a NOTE, `'::' or ':::' import not declared from: ‘devtools’`. Granted its just a note (so I could ignore it), but I prefer to limit reasons why the package might be rejected from CRAN.

Comment: yes this NOTE seems normal. 
But when you submit your package for CRAN, I think the vignette should contain `library(yourpackage)` instead of `devtools::load_all`. Check will pass, and vignette will build correctly as package is loaded when check

Answer (score 4):

If you look up Hadley Wickham's packages in github, you will see he includes a library(xyz) at the top of his vignette, e.g. https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/dplyr.Rmd

Then [his recommended](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/vignettes.html) way to build vignettes works:

> You can build all vignettes from the console with
>   `*devtools::build_vignettes()*`, but this is rarely useful. Instead
>   use `devtools::build()` to create a package bundle with the vignettes
>   included.

I believe this is what you will need to submit a package to CRAN.

It is a slow development cycle, though, so for active coding, you can insert a line with `devtools::load_all()` to use the knit in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an answer but this is how I solved the same issue when using a hand written vignette.

I'm not sure if this will work for build_vignette() but when I was having trouble knitting my vignette because of this same error, what I had to do was:

1. `<path/to/your/Rpackage>/NAMESPACE` I had to add `export(myFuncName)` for each function I want to use in the vignette along with `useDynLib(myPackageName)` once.
2. I had to specify a VignetteBuilder option in the `<path/to/your/Rpackage>/DESCRIPTION` file for me it is `VignetteBuilder: knitr`.